# Как установить TURN/STUN сервер для windows 7?

Tags: windows, сервер, webrtc

Мне нужно установить для TURN/STUN для WebRTC на компьютер для время разработки и теста. Или может где то бесплатно!

Comment: А в чём заключается вопрос?

Comment: Вопрос может кто нибудь устанавливал сервер TURN/STUN на windows или есть где бесплатный, я находил чисто на linux как устоновить.

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/projects/stuntman/ ? Не?